# Check collision between instantiated objects?

Tags: c#, unity

I am using a script to instantiate multiple objects having rigidbody with different velocities at different positions. I want to destroy two or more objects when they collide, but I'm not getting anything inside:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){}
```

The details of the object I'm instantiating. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKhgm.png

The script is attached to an empty GameObject and Instantiated GameObject is stored in a array of GameObjects:

```
 Block[0] = Instantiate(boxPiece) as GameObject;
```

where boxPiece is the Object I want to instantiate.
And I'm checking for collisions in this very same script.

Comment: Not enough detail here to really answer your question.  I'd suggest going through the documentation again, and possibly providing screenshots of the inspector window of the objects you're trying to collide with each other.  http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this Unity collision question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/60313/using-collideroncollisionentercollision-without-at.html) I created a new script with `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){}` and attached it to all the new Objects I'm creating in my script using `AddComponent("NewScriptName")` now it does detect collisions but I still feel that it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: That *is* the right way to do it.  `OnCollisionEnter` will only get called on the object that is doing the colliding.  Where was this `OnCollisionEnter` callback before?

Comment: It was inside the script which was instantiating these items using the code i mentioned in the question.

Comment: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter "OnCollisionEnter is called when *this* collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that the instantiated objects have a collider.
2. Are your objects moving at very high speeds? If they are they might jump over each other when they move faster than the length of the opposing collider.

Comment: 1. Yes they have Colliders.

2. No.

Comment: Hmm, could it be the collision layers then: [link]http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/Layer%20Based%20Collision%20detection

Comment: No everything is in default layer and every layer is checked in Physics.